# Changing the color of an Action Bar

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-appcompat

```
<style name="Theme_Base_App" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
<item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
```

I simply copied the above code to my styles.xml file and I copied

```
android:theme="@style/Theme_Base_App"
```

into my manifest file. How do I now change the color of this action bar?

Also, can someone explain me what exactly I am doing by using these lines of code? What is the manifest file for? And what am I doing in the Styles.xml file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To change your color just set the `colorPrimary` in your `colors.xml` file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources> 
    <color name="primary">your color</color>
</resources>
```

**Using this style** you are defining your custom theme inheriting from `AppCompat` theme.

```
  <!-- inherit from the material theme -->
  <style name="Theme_Base_App" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

    <!-- Main theme colors -->
    <!--   your app branding color for the app bar -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>

    <!--   darker variant for the status bar and contextual app bars -->
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>

  </style>
```

[image]

You can refer this link for [more info](http://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html).

**The Android Manifest** file presents essential information about your app to the Android system. With

```
android:theme
```

> you are defining a reference to a style resource defining a default theme for all activities in the application. Individual activities can override the default by setting their own theme attributes. For more information, see the Styles and Themes developer guide.

Here you can find more info about [Manifest](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html) and [application element](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html) in the Manifest.